# IE11 and JavaScript array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have run into problem under IE11. It throws an error

> Expected: ":"

for that line of code:

```
this.aAttachments = MessageStore.message().attachments().map(({fileName,mimeType,fileType,fileNameExt,download}) => [fileName,mimeType,fileType,fileNameExt,download]);
```

in the part

`{fileName,mimeType,fileType,fileNameExt,download}`

instead of commas.

Documentation says that IE support fully `map` [since IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)

Any clue on that?

Comment: The question is, does `MessageStore.message().attachments()` return an `Array` or an "array-like" object? In IE, you can only call `.map()` on true arrays, not "array-like" objects. If the return value is an array-like object, you'll need to explicitly convert it to an Array with `Array.prototype.slice.call(MessageStore.message().attachments())`.

Comment: Imho the destructuring is more a problem. [IE has no support for even basic destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility). Btw the error message already hints at that, it expects a `:` for a key:value pair because it's the only thing the parser could possibly expect.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it returns an array of objects like `[{key:value, key1:value},{key:value, key1:value},...]`

Comment: As a currently deleted (for different reasons) answer stated: [IE doesnt even support arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). Poor souls who have to support IE11 or even lower, really. I hope i never ever have to.

Comment: You should use a transpiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with map, I think the issue is that you're using a shortcut for assigning object properties to their own variables in that part you specified. I believe this is a relatively new feature to javascript so likely not supported by IE since it seems to lag far behind. I would suggest changing your inline function to

```
(obj) => [obj.fileName,obj.mimeType,obj.fileType,obj.fileNameExt,obj.download]
```

and see if that fixes it.

EDIT: Some people are also saying that IE does not support arrow functions either, so make that

```
function(obj) { return [obj.fileName,obj.mimeType,obj.fileType,obj.fileNameExt,obj.download]; }
```

Comment: IE doesn't support arrow functions, either, you need `function(obj)`

Comment: Looks promising when running on standalone IE11. I will verify how it comes when IE11 is emended in the main application.